# How can I use the four-argument form of getRange with SpreadSheetApp.openById()?

Tags: google-apps-script

```
var MasterSheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById("----------------");
var count = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange(2, 3, 6, 4).getNumColumns();
var count = MasterSheet.getRange("C2:F7").getNumColumns();
var count = MasterSheet.getRange(2, 3, 6, 4).getNumColumns();
```

Lines 2 and 3 work fine but line 4 gives the error "Cannot find method `getRange(number,number,number,number)`". It seems `getRange(number,..)` is available only for Active Sheet, not for `openById`.

Is this a bug? Does anyone know the correct way to use this notation with `SpreadsheetApp.openById()`?

Answer (score 6):

Since you are using openByID while running the script through trigger, there will be no active sheet. However you are trying to getRange from ActiveSheet, i.e getRange of undefined.
Either you first make a sheet active and then use getActiveSheet
or you may use

```
SpreadsheetApp.getSheets[0].getRange(...); //index may vary
//or 
SpreadsheetApp.getSheetByName('sheetName').getRange(...)
```

Comment: Waqar calling getActiveSheet on any Spreadsheet object never returns undefined. When the Spreadsheet is not the active one (e.g. when using openById or on a trigger, etc), getActiveSheet will return the first sheet. It only returns `undefined` if you call it directly from the `SpreadsheetApp` object (in a scenario where such sheet does not exist).

Comment: Many thanks Waqar and guys. I noticed I confused about two different objects Spreadsheet and Sheet. Now it's clear.

Comment: Thanks Henrique for the explanation. You really rock :)

Answer (score 5):

When you getRange directly on the Spreadsheet object instead of a Sheet one, like you're doing on lines 3 and 4, you're actually getting the range on the 1st sheet.

This is just a shortcut, you should really getSheets()[0], or even better, getSheetByName and call then getRange on it (the Sheet object). Because, as you noted, this is a shortcut, not the standard path. e.g. you got no short for getRange(int,int,int,int).

Answer (score 0):

you always have to select a sheet to then use getRange

`var count = MasterSheet.getRange("C2:F7").getNumColumns();

var count = MasterSheet.getRange(2, 3, 6, 4).getNumColumns();`

here you miss the `getActiveSheet()` or `getSheetByName('sheetName')`

Comment: not always Cartman, as you can see exemplified on the question.